# Bizarre behavior, loop function affects setup function

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, stepper

I've connected two stepper through two uln2003 chip. And wrote a small class to control them.
The class works perfectly and I'm able to control the steppers (rotate the CW and CCW).

My main code looks like this :

```
#include "StepperControl.h"

StepperControl myStepperControls[2];

void setup() {
    delay(1000);
    myStepperControls[0].init(6,5,4,3);
    myStepperControls[1].init(11,10,9,8);

    delay(1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        myStepperControls[i].DelayBetweenSteps = 1200;
        myStepperControls[i].StepCCWDegree(90);
        myStepperControls[i].StepCWDegree(51);
    }
}
int moveNumber = 0;
void loop(){
    int stepperNumber = moveNumber / 2;
    bool cw = ((moveNumber % 2)  == 0);
    moveNumber = (moveNumber + 1) % 4;
}
```

As you can see I:

- Init both instances of the class to different pins.
- Set the Delay between the steps (in microseconds).
- Rotate `myStepperControls[0]` counter clock wise and then clock wise.
- Same for `myStepperControls[1]`

This doesn't work correctly, one of the motors doesn't move clock wise.

It is not always the same motor !! For the last hour the problem appeared only in `myStepperControls[0]`, now it is only in `myStepperControls[1]`.

I'm 100% sure it is not a wiring/electrical problem because:

1. If I'll delete the content of the loop (which runs after setup) it will fix the problem.
2. If I'll make the delay between steps 2000 it will fix the problems.
3. As I've mentioned the problem was only in `myStepperControls[0]` for an hour, in that hour i switch the pins of the motors and still the motor that was connected to `myStepperControls[0]` was not able to rotate CW.

Any suggestions to how to investigate the problem will be appriciated

Here is my library code:

```
// StepperControl.h

#ifndef _STEPPERCONTROL_h
#define _STEPPERCONTROL_h

#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
    #include "arduino.h"
#else
    #include "WProgram.h"
#endif

class StepperControl
{
 public:
    StepperControl();
    void init(byte blue, byte pink, byte yellow, byte orange);
    void StepCW(int steps);
    void StepCCW(int steps);
    void StepCWDegree(float degrees);
    void StepCCWDegree(float degrees);
    const int StepsPerFullRotation = 4076;
    int DelayBetweenSteps;
 private:

    void setPinsState(byte step);

    byte m_currentState;
    byte m_pinValuelookup[9];

    byte m_bluePin; // = 11;    // Blue   - 28BYJ48 pin 1
    byte m_pinkPin; // = 10;    // Pink   - 28BYJ48 pin 2
    byte m_yellowPin; // = 9;    // Yellow - 28BYJ48 pin 3
    byte m_orangePin; // = 8;    // Orange - 28BYJ48 pin 4
                            // Red    - 28BYJ48 pin 5 (VCC)

};

#endif
```

here is the cpp file :

```
#include "StepperControl.h"

StepperControl::StepperControl() : m_pinValuelookup{B01000, B01100, B00100, B00110, B00010, B00011, B00001, B01001, B00000}, DelayBetweenSteps(1100), m_currentState(0)
{
}

void StepperControl::init(byte blue, byte pink, byte yellow, byte orange)
{
    m_bluePin = blue;
    m_pinkPin = pink;
    m_yellowPin = yellow;
    m_orangePin = orange;

    pinMode(m_bluePin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(m_pinkPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(m_yellowPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(m_orangePin, OUTPUT);
    delayMicroseconds(DelayBetweenSteps);
    setPinsState(8);
    delayMicroseconds(DelayBetweenSteps);
}

void StepperControl::StepCW(int steps)
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
    {
        m_currentState = (m_currentState - 1) % 8;
        setPinsState(m_currentState);
        delayMicroseconds(DelayBetweenSteps);
    }
    setPinsState(8);
}

void StepperControl::StepCCW(int steps)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
    {
        m_currentState = (m_currentState + 1) % 8;
        setPinsState(m_currentState);
        delayMicroseconds(DelayBetweenSteps);
    }
    setPinsState(8);
}

void StepperControl::StepCWDegree(float degrees)
{
    float steps = degrees * (float)StepsPerFullRotation / 360.0f;
    StepCW((int)steps);
}

void StepperControl::StepCCWDegree(float degrees)
{
    float steps = degrees * (float)StepsPerFullRotation / 360.0f;
    StepCCW((int)steps);
}

void StepperControl::setPinsState(byte step)
{
  digitalWrite(m_bluePin, bitRead(m_pinValuelookup[step], 0));
  digitalWrite(m_pinkPin, bitRead(m_pinValuelookup[step], 1));
  digitalWrite(m_yellowPin, bitRead(m_pinValuelookup[step], 2));
  digitalWrite(m_orangePin, bitRead(m_pinValuelookup[step], 3));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some one helped me in the Arduino forums, and I felt obligated to add the answer here :

The : `m_currentState = (m_currentState - 1) % 8;` is the bug.
I accidentally assumed that doing `%` on `-1` will jump to `7`.

Somehow this caused the strange behavior I had.

Answer (score 0):

You found the solution yourself. I am posting this answer anyway just to
give some background on the problem.

I must say you were somewhat unlucky: you have just hit a couple of the
least intuitive features of the C and C++ languages: integral promotion
and signed division.

1. **Integral promotion**: C does not know how to perform arithmetic on
   anything smaller than an int. When you write `m_currentState - 1`,
   the variable `m_currentState` is automatically promoted to `int`.
   Note that this promotion has converted an *unsigned* type (`byte` is
   unsigned) into a *signed* integer. Then, `(byte) 0 - 1` is `(int) -1`
   instead of `(byte) 255`.
2. **Signed division**: When dividing a negative number by a positive
   one, the quotient is rounded towards zero and, conversely, the rest
   is negative. Then, `-1 % 8` is -1 instead of 7.

There are several ways around these problems. One is to replace the
modulo operation `% 8` by a bitwise and: `& 7`. This is an optimization
the compiler would have done anyway if dealing with *unsigned* integers.
The option I prefer is to simply undo the integral promotion by an
explicit cast:

```
m_currentState = (byte) (m_currentState - 1) % 8;
```

This way, if `m_currentState` is zero, `(byte) (m_currentState - 1)` is
255 and the result is, as expected, 7. Also, the compiler optimizes the
unsigned modulo operation into a bitwise and: the whole lines compiles
very efficiently into just two single-cycle instructions:

```
subi r24, 0x01  ; subtract 1
andi r24, 0x07  ; bitwise and with 7
```

It is worth noting that nothing of this would have happened if
`m_currentState` was an `unsigned int`, as there would have been no
integral promotion in the first place.